# Cypher CREATE returns no results

Tags: neo4j

I am sending the following cypher query within a Neo4j transaction using the Embedded Neo4j Java API:

```
CREATE (n:Competition {props}) RETURN n
```

The node is created but no results are returned and I get an empty result back from `GraphDatabaseService.execute(..)`

Am I missing something obvious here?

This is with Neo4j 2.3

Comment: Can you please post the code you're using to execute the query, and indicate what code you're using that shows nothing returned?

Comment: It is this line that always fails https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-neo4j/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/neo4j/engine/Neo4jEntityPersister.java#L559

It is currently causing this test failure:

https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-neo4j/src/test/groovy/grails/gorm/tests/NativeIdentityGeneratorSpec.groovy#L27

Comment: LOL, I see the bug, ignore me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the code and can be ignored.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Do note that the peculiar create syntax that takes a list/array/collection (if your `props` parameter were an array of maps/objects) has been deprecated, per http://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-2-3-0/. You can achieve the same with `FOREACH` or `UNWIND`.